# Filtering multi level groupby results

Tags: python, pandas, filter, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a multi-level groupby that returns the count of grouped rows per grouping from my dataframe. It displays it in a new column without a label. I am trying to filter for counts NOT equal to 6. I tried creating an index of True/False for that, but I do not know how to get back the results from the index. I also tried filter and lambda combinations without success.

Here is code, where person, WL (wavelength), file and threshold are columns in my dataframe (df_new).

```
df_new.groupby([df_new['Person'], df_new['WL'], df_new['File'], 
df_new['Threshold']])['RevNum'].count()
```

I get back a list of the counts, however, that's as far as I can get. I'm not able to figure out how to see only the records that are NOT equal to 6.

For example, towards the bottom of the results there is this entry:

```
656  TRW-2017-04-25_60_584  0            5
```

A larger example of results:

```
Person  WL   File                   Threshold
AEM     440  AEM-2018-05-23_11_440  0            6
                                    1            6
             AEM-2018-05-23_50_440  0            6
                                    1            6
        452  AEM-2018-05-23_11_440  0            6
                                    1            6
             AEM-2018-05-23_50_440  0            6
                                    1            6
        464  AEM-2018-05-23_11_440  0            6
                                    1            6
             AEM-2018-05-23_50_440  0            6
                                    1            6
        476  AEM-2018-05-23_11_440  0            6
                                    1            6
             AEM-2018-05-23_50_440  0            6
                                    1            6
        488  AEM-2018-05-23_11_440  0            6
                                    1            6
             AEM-2018-05-23_50_440  0            6
                                    1            6
AGC     440  AGC-2018-05-25_12_440  0            6
                                    1            6
             AGC-2018-05-25_50_440  0            6
                                    1            6
        452  AGC-2018-05-25_12_440  0            6
                                    1            6
             AGC-2018-05-25_50_440  0            6
                                    1            6
        464  AGC-2018-05-25_12_440  0            6
                                    1            6
                                                ..
TRW     620  TRW-2017-04-08_60_572  0            6
                                    1            6
        632  TRW-2017-04-25_60_584  0            6
                                    1            6
        644  TRW-2017-04-08_60_572  0            6
                                    1            6
        656  TRW-2017-04-25_60_584  0            5
                                    1            6
             TRW-2017-04-25_60_656  0            6
                                    1            6
```

When I change my code to:

```
df_counts = df_new.groupby([df_new['Person'], df_new['WL'], df_new['File'], 
df_new['Threshold']])['RevNum'].count()
```

It stores it as a series and not a dataframe, and I cannot access the last column with the values (the count results of my groupby).

When I try:

```
df_counts_grouped = df_new.groupby([df_new['Person'], df_new['WL'], 
                    df_new['File'], df_new['Threshold']])['RevNum'].count()
df_counts_grouped.filter(lambda x: x['B'].max() != 6)
```

I tried .max, .min, .count etc.

It says that 'function' object is not iterable.
I believe that a series is not iterable?
Any help filtering my groupby results is appreciated.

If I could get the results of the groupby into a new dataframe and rename the resulting "count" column, I could access it. Not sure how to send the results of my groupby with count to a new dataframe. Alternatively, I am not sure how to use the results to only select the appropriate rows from the first dataframe, since it's a count of many of the rows in the original dataframe.

The dataframe looks like this to begin with, before doing any groupby stuff.

```
File    Threshold   StepSize    RevNum  WL  RevPos  BkgdLt  Person  Date    AbRevPos    ExpNum  EarlyEnd
48  AEM-2018-05-23_11_440   1   1.50    7.0 464 -2.07   11  AEM 2018-05-23  2.07    Two NaN
49  AEM-2018-05-23_11_440   1   0.82    8.0 464 -3.57   11  AEM 2018-05-23  3.57    Two NaN
50  AEM-2018-05-23_11_440   1   1.50    7.0 488 -2.58   11  AEM 2018-05-23  2.58    Two NaN
54  AEM-2018-05-23_11_440   1   0.82    8.0 488 -5.58   11  AEM 2018-05-23  5.58    Two NaN
55  AEM-2018-05-23_11_440   1   1.50    7.0 440 -3.00   11  AEM 2018-05-23  3.00    Two NaN

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 3286 entries, 48 to 7839
Data columns (total 12 columns):
File         3286 non-null object
Threshold    3286 non-null int64
StepSize     3286 non-null float64
RevNum       3286 non-null float64
WL           3286 non-null int64
RevPos       3286 non-null float64
BkgdLt       3286 non-null int32
Person       3286 non-null object
Date         3286 non-null datetime64[ns]
AbRevPos     3286 non-null float64
ExpNum       3286 non-null object
EarlyEnd     0 non-null float64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(5), int32(1), int64(2), object(3)
memory usage: 320.9+ KB
```

This code:

```
df_counts_grouped = df_new.groupby([df_new['Person'], df_new['WL'], df_new['File'], df_new['Threshold']])['RevNum'].count()
df_counts_grouped.head(10)
```

Produces this output:

```
Person  WL   File                   Threshold
AEM     440  AEM-2018-05-23_11_440  0            6
                                    1            6
             AEM-2018-05-23_50_440  0            6
                                    1            6
        452  AEM-2018-05-23_11_440  0            6
                                    1            6
             AEM-2018-05-23_50_440  0            6
                                    1            6
        464  AEM-2018-05-23_11_440  0            6
                                    1            6
Name: RevNum, dtype: int64
```

I have found the beginning of an answer to my question, which lies in syntax. It lies in the difference between Pandas Series and Pandas DataFrames!

```
df_new.groupby('Person')['WL'].count() # produces Pandas Series
df_new.groupby('Person')[['WL']].count() # Produces Pandas DataFrame
```

Found at: https://shanelynn.ie/summarising-aggregation-and-grouping-data-in-python-pandas/

Comment: You need to work on creating a MCVE.  [See this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: And especially post an excerpt or example of your original data set!

Answer (score 1):

I have created a quick minimal complete and verifiable example for you:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Letter':['a', 'b']*2, 'Number':[1]*3+[2]})

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
  Letter  Number
0      a       1
1      b       1
2      a       1
3      b       2

In [4]: df.groupby(['Letter', 'Number'])['Number'].count()
Out[4]: 
Letter  Number
a       1         2
b       1         1
        2         1
Name: Number, dtype: int64

In [5]: grouped_counts = df.groupby(['Letter', 'Number'])['Number'].count()

In [6]: type(grouped_counts)
Out[6]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

As you can see, the maximum number of counts is 2, so let's filter for all groups that gave counts lower than 2:

```
In [7]: grouped_counts.loc[grouped_counts<2]
Out[7]: 
Letter  Number
b       1         1
        2         1
```

Comment: This is a great solution if I want every single record that makes up the count returned to me. Having a summary DataFrame worked better for me: df_counts_grouped = df_new.groupby([df_new['Person'], df_new['WL'], df_new['File'], df_new['Threshold']])[['RevNum']].count() with df_counts_grouped[df_counts_grouped['RevNum'] != 6]

Comment: I might be wrong but I think we're doing the same thing in our answers but great that you found a solution that works for you yourself, that's always much better! You `groupby` and convert to a DataFrame before indexing on your column of interest, I index directly on the series that groupby returns in this case (notice that in your example the series you get has the name `RevNum`). In my quick and dirty MCVE, the `Number` column is your `RevNum` column.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! It was a super simple syntax issue of changing from a Series to a DataFrame!

```
df_new.groupby('Person')['WL'].count() # produces Pandas Series
df_new.groupby('Person')[['WL']].count() # Produces Pandas DataFrame
```

Found at: https://shanelynn.ie/summarising-aggregation-and-grouping-data-in-python-pandas/

My code now looks like this and I can get back only the entries where the Reversal Number (RevNum) is not 6.

```
df_counts_grouped = df_new.groupby([df_new['Person'], df_new['WL'], df_new['File'], df_new['Threshold']])[['RevNum']].count()

df_counts_grouped[df_counts_grouped['RevNum'] != 6]
```

The simple change from single brackets around 'RevNum':

```
df_counts_grouped = df_new.groupby([df_new['Person'], df_new['WL'], df_new['File'], df_new['Threshold']])['RevNum'].count()
```

To double brackets around my column label, 'RevNum':

```
df_counts_grouped = df_new.groupby([df_new['Person'], df_new['WL'], df_new['File'], df_new['Threshold']])[['RevNum']].count()
```

Fixed everything!